# Exclude spaces when reading a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting into file handling in python and want to read the info in a file. How do I read the file without additional lines?

Here's my code:

```py
data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Using [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip): `print(line.rstrip())`

Comment: BTW, `f.readlines()` read whole file. If you don't need those lines all at once, just iterate the file. `for line in f: ...`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "additional lines"? It could just be that you're printing additional lines, try `print(line, end="")`

Comment: @Speeeddy I mean blank lines. Equivalent to printing out \n which is exactly what happens if you add the information to a tuple

Answer (score 3):

Incorporating falsetru's point,

```
for line in f:
    if line.strip():
        print(line)
```

The `strip` command will strip all white space, and at that point, if you have an empty string, the condition will fail.